# Error compiling pyside2 : No such file or directory qabstracttransition_wrapper.cpp

Tags: compiling, qt

I try to compile PySide2 on my centos 7
I already successfully  compiled Qt5.10 and Cmake 3.10.2
Then I clone PySide5.6 from git, and use this command to cmpile PySide2:

```
python setup.py install --qmake=/apps/shared/qt5/5.10.0/bin/qmake --cmake=/apps/shared/cmake/3.10.2/bin/cmake --prefix=/tmp/5.6 --jobs=12
```

But It always casts a error :

> **c++: error: /home/isaac/Desktop/studio/pyside-setup/pyside2_build/py2.7-qt5.10.1-64bit-release/pyside2/PySide2/QtCore/PySide2/QtCore/qabstractstate_wrapper.cpp: No such file or directory
>   c++: fatal error: no input files
>
> c++: error: /home/isaac/Desktop/studio/pyside-setup/pyside2_build/py2.7-qt5.10.1-64bit-release/pyside2/PySide2/QtCore/PySide2/QtCore/qabstracttransition_wrapper.cpp: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.
>   make[2]: *** [PySide2/QtCore/CMakeFiles/QtCore.dir/PySide2/QtCore/qabstractstate_wrapper.cpp.o]
>
> Error 4
>   c++: fatal error: no input files
>
> make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
>   compilation terminated.
>   make[2]:**  [PySide2/QtCore/CMakeFiles/QtCore.dir/PySide2/QtCore/qabstracttransition_wrapper.cpp.o] Error 4
>   [  4%] Building CXX object PySide2/QtCore/CMakeFiles/QtCore.dir/PySide2/QtCore/qabstractitemmodel_wrapper.cpp.o
>   make[1]:  **[PySide2/QtCore/CMakeFiles/QtCore.dir/all] Error 2
>   make: *** [all] Error 2
>   error: Error compiling pyside2
>   **

This problem has  already bothered me for 4 days! Did I make something wrong ? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

PySide2 5.6 does't support Qt5.10.0.So if you want using Qt5.10.0 you must upgrade PySide2 to 5.9.And one more useful detail, the CMakeLists.txt under

> ~/pyside-setup/sources/shiboken2

require clang 3.9 and llvm 3.9, but if you are using 3.9 version to compile PySide2 it would cast a error:

> shiboken: Error running ApiExtractor.

You need upgrade Clang 5.0 and llvm 5.0 to compile PySide2.